# MapView in a VC and its Searchbar in another

Tags: swift3, mkmapview, uisearchbar

As per the title, in general I'd like to show, in one VC, a MapView and in a second VC a SearchBar (using another TableVC to display, as the user types, "GeoElements" obtained by MKLocalSearchRequest). This because I want to display in the Map some AnnotationViews with custom Callouts. My problem is that the TableVC doesn't update with placemarks as the user types in the SearchBar..

MAPVIEW code:

```
    import UIKit
import MapKit


protocol HandleMapSearch {
    func dropPinZoomIn(placemark:MKPlacemark)
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {


    @IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!







    let locationManager = CLLocationManager()

    var selectedPin:MKPlacemark? = nil




    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyThreeKilometers
        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        locationManager.requestLocation()


    }

    func getDirections(){
        if let selectedPin = selectedPin {
            let mapItem = MKMapItem(placemark: selectedPin)
            let launchOptions = [MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeKey : MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeDriving]
            mapItem.openInMaps(launchOptions: launchOptions)
        }
    }
}

extension ViewController : CLLocationManagerDelegate {
    private func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorizationStatus status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
        if status == .authorizedWhenInUse {
            locationManager.requestLocation()
        }
    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        if let location = locations.first {
            let span = MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.05, 0.05)
            let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: location.coordinate, span: span)
            mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)
        }
    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: Error) {
        print("error:: (error)")
    }
}

extension ViewController: HandleMapSearch {
    func dropPinZoomIn(placemark:MKPlacemark){
        // cache the pin
        selectedPin = placemark
        let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
        annotation.coordinate = placemark.coordinate
        annotation.title = placemark.name
        if let city = placemark.locality,
            let state = placemark.administrativeArea {
            annotation.subtitle = "(city) (state)"
        }
        mapView.addAnnotation(annotation)
        let span = MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.05, 0.05)
        let region = MKCoordinateRegionMake(placemark.coordinate, span)
        mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)
    }
}


    extension ViewController : MKMapViewDelegate {
        func mapView(_: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView?{
            if annotation is MKUserLocation {
                //return nil so map view draws "blue dot" for standard user location
                return nil
            }
            let reuseId = "pin"
            var pinView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: reuseId) as? MKPinAnnotationView
            pinView = MKPinAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: reuseId)
            pinView?.pinTintColor = UIColor.orange
            pinView?.canShowCallout = true
            let smallSquare = CGSize(width: 30, height: 30)
            let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: 0,y :0), size: smallSquare))
            button.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "car"), for: .normal)
            button.addTarget(self, action: Selector(("getDirections")), for: .touchUpInside)
            pinView?.leftCalloutAccessoryView = button
            return pinView
        }
    }
```

EVENT code:

```
import UIKit
import MapKit

class EventVC: UIViewController {







    var resultSearchController:UISearchController? = nil

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let locationSearchTable = storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "LocationSearchTable") as! LocationSearchTable
        resultSearchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: locationSearchTable)
        resultSearchController?.searchResultsUpdater = locationSearchTable


        let searchBar = resultSearchController!.searchBar
        searchBar.sizeToFit()
        searchBar.placeholder = "Insert Address"
        navigationItem.titleView = resultSearchController?.searchBar


        resultSearchController?.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
        resultSearchController?.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = true
        definesPresentationContext = true

        //these two below are problematic
        locationSearchTable.mapView = mapView
        locationSearchTable.handleMapSearchDelegate = self
    }

}
```

LOCATIONSEARCHTABLE code:

```
import UIKit
import MapKit

class LocationSearchTable: UITableViewController {


    var matchingItems:[MKMapItem] = []
    var mapView: MKMapView? = nil

    var handleMapSearchDelegate:HandleMapSearch? = nil


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }


    func parseAddress(selectedItem:MKPlacemark) -> String {
        // put a space between "4" and "Melrose Place"
        let firstSpace = (selectedItem.subThoroughfare != nil && selectedItem.thoroughfare != nil) ? " " : ""
        // put a comma between street and city/state
        let comma = (selectedItem.subThoroughfare != nil || selectedItem.thoroughfare != nil) && (selectedItem.subAdministrativeArea != nil || selectedItem.administrativeArea != nil) ? ", " : ""
        // put a space between "Washington" and "DC"
        let secondSpace = (selectedItem.subAdministrativeArea != nil && selectedItem.administrativeArea != nil) ? " " : ""
        let addressLine = String(
            format:"%@%@%@%@%@%@%@",
            // street number
            selectedItem.subThoroughfare ?? "",
            firstSpace,
            // street name
            selectedItem.thoroughfare ?? "",
            comma,
            // city
            selectedItem.locality ?? "",
            secondSpace,
            // state
            selectedItem.administrativeArea ?? ""
        )
        return addressLine
    }
}

extension LocationSearchTable : UISearchResultsUpdating {
    func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController){
        guard let mapView = mapView,
            let searchBarText = searchController.searchBar.text else { return }
        let request = MKLocalSearchRequest()
        request.naturalLanguageQuery = searchBarText
        request.region = mapView.region
        let search = MKLocalSearch(request: request)
        search.start { response, _ in
            guard let response = response else {
                return
            }
            self.matchingItems = response.mapItems
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }

}

extension LocationSearchTable {
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return matchingItems.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell")!
        let selectedItem = matchingItems[indexPath.row].placemark
        cell.textLabel?.text = selectedItem.name
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = parseAddress(selectedItem: selectedItem)
        return cell
    }
}
```

Comment: Please include code so that someone can attempt to help.

Comment: @Varedis right, done